Resolving Color Inconsistencies and Accessibility Issues with Razor Components in .NET 6 Project
I'm conducting research to solve an issue in my .NET 6 project. I'm experiencing some inconsistencies and color problems in Visual Studio regarding a razor library I've added to my main project. Specifically, I've noticed that when using components from the added razor library in my main project, all of them appear in blue instead of green. This situation prevents me from accessing the source when clicking on the components and occasionally causes Visual Studio to freeze.
Now, I'm seeking information on the following topics to resolve this issue:

Ensuring compatibility and resolving inconsistencies between .NET 6 projects.

Resolving color issues in Visual Studio and making component sources accessible.

Solution suggestions shared by developers who have had similar experiences.

Tips on integrating and configuring razor libraries correctly.


If there are any resources such as articles, forum posts, or GitHub repositories containing information on these topics, please share. Additionally, I'd be glad to communicate with individuals who have encountered and resolved a similar issue.
Thank you in advance for your assistance.
Best regards,
Mehmet Kent
Attempts Made:
Removed and re-added the Razor library.
Tried different versions of Visual Studio.
Removed and re-added namespaces.
Expectation: Resolution of the issue with Razor components displaying correct colors and being accessible.
Outcome: Unfortunately, despite all these attempts, the issue remains unresolved, and the Razor components still appear in the wrong color and inaccessible.

What project are you using? Can you    provide a minimal reproducible example and steps to help us reproduce your problem? See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.
